# Distribute items evenly over any number of categories

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I would like to write a main method that distributes data to "age" categories.
Each data item has and age. An age categorie spans 5 year so 0-5, 5-10, 10-15, etc.
I want only the categories with items in it shown.

So if the input would be:

Richard, 15

Helen, 24

Steven, 16

Edwin,19

Frederick, 12

The output would be something like:

Calculated categories:

0-5, 5-10, 10-15, 15-20, 20-25

Distribution:

10-15: Frederick

15-20: Richard, Steven, Edwin

20-25: Helen

Comment: What is the question/What have you tried?

Comment: `HashMap<AgeRangeEnum, List<String>>` is your friend. You should at least post the code you tried, and specify where your problem is.

Comment: At least try buddy...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<Integer, List<String>> result = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    while (true) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (!line.contains(",")) {
            System.out.println("incorrect input string");
            continue;
        }

        String name = line.split(",")[0];
        String age = line.split(",")[1];
        age = age.trim();
        int ageInt = -1;
        try {
            ageInt = Integer.parseInt(age);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("age not a number");
            continue;
        }

        ageInt = ageInt - ageInt % 5;
        List<String> names = result.get(ageInt);
        if (names ==  null) {
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        names.add(name);
        result.put(ageInt, names);

        printResult(result);
    }
}

private static void printResult(Map<Integer, List<String>> result) {
    List<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ages.addAll(result.keySet());
    Collections.sort(ages);

    for (Integer integer : ages) {
        List<String> name2 = result.get(integer);
        System.out.println(integer + " - " + (integer + 5) + " : ");
        for (String s : name2) {
            System.out.println("     " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the question?